# Setting API call data as state, but having problems assigning type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm building a simple TypeScript project using the NASA API. To begin with I'm simply making a get request for a single object in my `Earth.tsx` component, and then trying to render the data to the browser.

API data being saved to state:

```
{
date: '2018-01-03T16:50:46.890000',
 id: 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_025039_20180103', 
resource: {…}, 
service_version: 'v5000', 
url: 'https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/project…bccd48-3aa76fabdd69b028540a8edb2800e72b:getPixels'
}
```

The problem is that when I try to render the data, I get the error

> Object is possibly undefined

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I have a feeling it's to do with the type I've assgined to my state.

`Earth.tsx`

```
import { useState, useEffect,FC } from "react"
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios"

const Earth = ():JSX.Element => {

    interface IEarth {
        date:string,
        id:string,
        resource:{
            dataset:string,
            planet:string
        }
        service_version: string,
        url: string
    }

    // type PhotoPayload = IEarth[]

    const [data,setData] = useState<IEarth>()
    const url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=-95.33&lat=29.78&date=2018-01-01&&dim=0.10&api_key=DEMO_KEY'

    const getData = ():void => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
            setData(res.data)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    },[])

    console.log('data', data)

    return(
        <div>
            {data.url}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Earth
```

Comment: totally worked! How does the ternary operator work in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` in `{data.url}`, so it becomes `{data?.url}`

> The `?.` operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead
> of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the
> expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
import { useState, useEffect,FC } from "react"
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios"

const Earth = ():JSX.Element => {

    interface IEarth {
        date:string,
        id:string,
        resource:{
            dataset:string,
            planet:string
        }
        service_version: string,
        url: string
    }

    // type PhotoPayload = IEarth[]

    const [data,setData] = useState<IEarth>()
    const url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=-95.33&lat=29.78&date=2018-01-01&&dim=0.10&api_key=DEMO_KEY'

    const getData = ():void => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
            setData(res.data)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    },[])

    console.log('data', data)

    return(
        <div>
            {data?.url}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Earth
```